# Find first indices of the N largest values of a numpy array without sorting in-place

Tags: python, numpy

I need to find first indices of the N largest values of a numpy array without sorting in-place.
Examples:

```
1) Find indices of 2 largest values in an array: [0, 0.5, 1, 0.5]
   result: [1,2] (or [2,1], order of returned indices doesn't matter])

2) Find indices of 2 largest values in an array: [0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5]
   result: [0,1]

3) Find indices of 3 largest values in an array:[0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.75, 0.55, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.5]
   result: [1, 7, 3]

4) Find indices of 6 largest values in an array:[0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.75, 0.55, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.5]
    result: [1, 7, 3, 5, 6, 2]
```

If the smallest of the numbers to be returned isn't unique, it's important the function returns the indices of ones that are the closest to the beginning of the array.

I tried to do it this way:

```
example = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.,  0.5, 0.5])
ind = np.argpartition(example, -N)[-N:]
```

but for N=2 this returns ind = [1,4]. There is an order parameter in np.argpartition() but I don't understand how I should use it.

90% of the time the array size will be around 25, 9% of time the size will be no greater than 100, edge case is limited to 1000 elements.

Because the array size will always be qutie small, I built a naive solution that works but it's surely sub-optimal:

```
import numpy as np

def nlar_idx(array, n):
    d = dict()
    for value, key in enumerate(array):
        if key not in d.keys():
            d[key] = [value]
        else:
            d[key].append(value)   
    do = dict(sorted(d.items(), reverse=True))
    out = [x for v in do.values() for x in v][:n]
    return out

array = np.array([0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.75, 0.55, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.5])
n = 3
res = nlar_idx(array, n)
print(res)
# [1, 7, 3]
```

Any way to make it work with argpartition() or build a better version of my function? We want to optimize for execution time only, memory doesn't matter.

Comment: What character are the values of input array? Do you have only few unique values (e.g. 0.3, 0.5, 0.55, ...) or the  values are random?

Comment: floats ranging from 0.0 to 0.9999999. It can happen that values will be unique, but in general there will be a few overlapping numbers in most cases. It may happen that the array will have overlapping numbers only, for example [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]. Values in array do not follow any distribution and can be thought of as random numbers in the range of 0.0 to 0.9999999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `np.argsort`, but on the opposite of the list, because if there are multiples, argsort returns last occurence, and not the first. Here you go :

```py
import numpy as np

examples = [
    [2, [0, 0.5, 1, 0.5]],
    [2, [0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5]],
    [3, [0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.75, 0.55, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.5]],
    [6, [0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.75, 0.55, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.5]]
]

def compute(n_max, data):
    data = -1*np.array(data)
    return np.argsort(data)[:n_max]

for ex in examples:
    print(compute(ex[0], ex[1]))
```

And the result is :

```
[2 1]
[0 1]
[1 7 3]
[1 7 3 5 6 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. The unique approach doesn't work because we want to return duplicated numbers as well if they are contained in N largest set, as in example 2) I provided. If we wanted to return indices of 4 largest elements, your code would return [1, 7, 3, 2], but it should return [1, 7, 3, 5].
Edit: added extra example in the main post.

Comment: I edited, please have a look :)

Comment: I think it works, very nice solution, thanks you :)

Comment: Nice :) Please don't forget to +1 and set my answer as solution :) See you

Answer (score 0):

This returns `[1, 7, 3, 5]` for n = 4.

```
import numpy as np


def n_largest(arr, n):
    # Use partition to get the indices of the n largest elements
    indices = np.argpartition(arr, -n)[-n:]

    # Sort the selected indices based on their corresponding values
    # (you can skip this step if you don't want them in order)
    indices = indices[np.argsort(arr[indices])[::-1]]

    # Return the n largest elements and their indices
    return arr[indices], indices


# Example usage:
arr = np.array([0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.75, 0.55, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.5])
n = 4
result, indices = n_largest(arr, n)

print(f"The {n} largest elements are: {result}")
print(f"Their indices are: {indices}")
```

> The 4 largest elements are: [0.9  0.8  0.75 0.75]

> Their indices are: [1 7 3 5]

Comment: Thank you for contributing, but this doesn't work for example case 2) 
arr = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5]) and N = 2. 
It returns [4,1], should return [0,1].

Answer (score 0):

It feels like `np.argsort` is a solution.

```
idx = np.argsort(array)[-N:]
```

`np.argsort` returns a list of indices that would sort an array, ascending. Then we slice in a way that only N last indices are left.

I think this is allowed: yes, we perform sorting, but not in place (since the target array remains unchanged).

We can later use `np.where` to find elements closest to beginning of an array. Combined result would be

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5])
N=2
idx = np.flip(np.argsort(arr)[-N:])
out = np.zeros(0,dtype = int)
for ind in idx:
    sub_out = np.where(arr == arr[ind])[0]
    out = np.concatenate([out,sub_out])
    if len(out)>N:
        out = out [:N]
        break
Output: [0,1]
```

The code iterates over `idx` array providing `arr[ind]` -- biggest values. We later scan the target array for these values with `np.where` and concatenate results (same values, but closer to beginning). If we have acquried enough elements (>N), we break out and truncate array at desired `N` values.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. For arr = np.array([0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.75, 0.55, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.5]) and N=4, the output is wrong. The out array is messed up ([3,5,6,3]) and idx it returns are [5,6,7,1] instead of [1,3,5,7].

Comment: You are right! Fixed a mistake, the argsort result should be flipped (forgot to type), so the search starts from the max to min. Also, I believe, the correct output in your example is [1,7,3,5] (there's 0.8 on 7th pos), unless the indices should be sorted afterwards.

Comment: The resulting array doesn't need to be sorted, so both outputs are correct, they point to the same elements. I think your code works now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Given your lists are relatively short I'd be tempted to go with a vanilla Python approach.  The [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module provides methods to collect `n`-extreme values relatively efficiently.

```
import heapq

def nlargest(lst, n):
    what = zip(lst, range(0, -len(lst), -1))
    return [-i for _, i in heapq.nlargest(n, what)]
```

it's slightly complicated due to your desire to get the largest values, but smallest indicies.

Comment: Thank you very much, good idea. I marked @Tricotou as accepted answer as his solution is computationally faster, but yours is great as well.

Comment: interestingly mine seems slightly faster when given larger Python lists, e.g. when `lst = np.random.rand(10000).tolist()` running `nlargest(lst, 6)` takes 1.6milliseconds while @Tricotou's `compute(6, lst)` takes 2.1ms.

Comment: For size of 10000 that is correct, but as mentioned in my post, my lists won't be bigger than 1000 elements. In such case Tricotou's method seems to run faster and I need to run this algo 10000 times but for small lists.

N = 10, np.random.rand(1000).tolist()
Sam Mason: 99.1 µs ± 104 ns per loop
Tricotou: 72.6 µs ± 323 ns per loop

N = 50, np.random.rand(1000).tolist()
Sam Mason: 185 µs ± 534 ns per loop
Tricotou: 72.8 µs ± 782 ns per loop

N = 5, np.random.rand(100).tolist()
Sam Mason: 15.8 µs ± 60.9 ns per loop
Tricotou: 10.7 µs ± 38.9 ns per loop

Comment: yup, mine is certainly a bit slower for small lists.  I was just surprised that it was faster for longer lists...  My expectations based on using numpy previously was that for short computations the overhead of numpy's method dispatch made Python faster for "small" things but it always dominated once the lists got big